# How do i do complex queries in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to **apply filters in query before i make the request**, so i do this :

`ref.where("status", "==", "online").onSnapshot ...`

This is a very simple filter, but i want to do something more complicated than this, for example:

I want to read documents from collection "users", I want to get the users that have a position that is 3 km away from point A (using longitude and latitude of the users), and the status of that user is "online", and the ID of that user is different of the current user ID.

**How can I do something like this**

Comment: We can't build your query for you because we can't see your data and we don't really know what specifically you're stuck on.  But you should look into something called GeoFirestore to help you with geo queries.

Comment: I can solve this problem after requesting, but if there are a large number of documents, this will lead to a large increase in the number of readings, and this is a big problem ... What is the solution that I can do?

Comment: Limit the result of the query by calling `limit(n)`.

Comment: but if i limit the result of the query i may not get all the correct results

Comment: I agree with the above; the question is pretty vague. But more importantly, your question states - *I want to get the users that have a position that is 3 km away* - but your comment states - *but if there are a large number of documents...large increase in the number of readings*. That's 100% accurate but you cannot have it both ways; if your objective is to *get* those users then you have to pay to get them, right? The solution is to limit the number of users - perhaps by if they are a friend or not. Or maybe only those that like pizza. Any parameters that will limit the dataset would help.

Comment: @Jay I think his point is that he don't want to be fetching unneeded users. Let me put some numbers to illustrate what he is saying. Let's say that he has 20 000 users, out of those only 5000 are online at the moment and out of those only 15 are within 3km. Fetching only based on Geo would return him 1000 reads for example and filter by status would return him 5000 reads. Keep adding zeros to that and you see where it's going.

Comment: @AK-dev Good info. I think you may have overlooked what I stated in my comment **The solution is to limit the number of users** - so as mentioned, there needs to be additional parameters included in the query to take the 20,000 users and only get the 5000 they want. However, there's not enough info in the question to know anything more than the three parameters included in the question; 3km, online, ≠ current user id. If that's still retrieving too many users, another parameter is needed to further reduce the count. Firebase only returns users that match the query, *not all users*.

Comment: @Jay I don't thing the solution is in having more filtering options, because the issue is not being able to combine a simple filter with a Geo Query. Having more fields won't solve the fact that you cannot optimally run both filtering at the same time, therefore, forcing you to fetch unnecessary documents to then manually filter based on the remaining condition. Same thing with limiting the results using `limit(n)` which would give you inconsistent results. But I do agree with you, this question needed more context to it.

Comment: @AK-dev You can certainly run both (or more!) filtering at the same time; Firestore has flexible filtering by many fields and parameters. I would guess the OP is using [GeoFirestore](https://geofirestore.com) which provides simple to implement geoquery filtering. OP - If you are not using that, I suggest looking at it for your geoqueries and take a look at the Firestore Getting Started Guide for [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) for a solution. If you can add your structure we may be able to help further.